# Vue $emit event triggering but this.$root.$on does nothing

Tags: vue.js, paypal

I am using vue-paypal-checkout to take payment which fires off an event based on the response from paypal.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paypal-checkout

Events:
payment-authorized
payment-completed
payment-cancelled

I see the events being fired in the Vue devtools so I know that is working but my event listener doesn't seem to be working.

My component looks like this:

```
    
<template>
    <div>
        <PayPal
            :client="paypal"
            :amount="cartTotalPrice"
            :currency="customer.currency"
            :env="paypalEnvironment"
            :button-style="paypalStyle"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import PayPal from 'vue-paypal-checkout';

export default {
    components: {
        PayPal,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            paypalStyle: {
                shape: 'rect',
                size: 'responsive',
                height: 48,
            },
        };
    },
    computed: {
        paypalEnvironment() {
            return (this.customer.paypalTestingMode) ? 'sandbox' : 'production';
        },
        paypal() {
            return {
                sandbox: this.customer.paypalClientIdTEST,
                production: this.customer.paypalClientIdLIVE,
            };
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('payment-authorized', event => {
            console.log('authorized');
            console.log(event);
        });
        this.$root.$on('payment-completed', event => {
            console.log('completed');
            console.log(event);
        });
        this.$root.$on('payment-cancelled', event => {
            console.log('cancelled');
            console.log(event);
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <PayPal
            :client="paypal"
            :amount="cartTotalPrice"
            :currency="customer.currency"
            :env="paypalEnvironment"
            :button-style="paypalStyle"
            @payment-authorized="paymentAuthorized" // ADD THIS
        />
    </div>
</template>

methods: {
    paymentAuthorized() {
        alert('authorized'); // HANDLE EVENT HERE
    },
},
```